# Is passing class methods directly as a callback possible when using prototypes?

Tags: javascript, callback, prototype

Let's say one wants to be able to add callbacks like this:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', class.method);
```

The problem with this  approach is that 'this' will not longer point to the right object, so methods have to be created using the `var self = this;` trick:

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
  var self = this;

  this.printName = function(){ console.log(self.name); };
}

var person = new Person('Bob');

// Creating a button to have an event listener to subscribe to
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.innerHTML = "print name";
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(btn);

// Actual example
btn.addEventListener('click', person.printName);
```

However, it seems that the approach above is incompatible with prototypes. Is there any way to make prototypes work for myClass in this line `addCallback(myClass.myMethod)` if support of old browsers is not a requirement and latest javascript features can be used?

I'm aware of `bind` and this approach `addCallback(person.printName.bind(person));` , but, in my opinion, it looks even worse than standard syntactic noise like `function () { person.printName ();}` , because at least the latter variant of noise people are more used to tune out.

If there is no solution to this, then are any potential (perhaps subjective) code aesthetics benefits worth potential performance degradation? The way I understand it prototypes provide faster performance on object creation, but not necessarily when using methods once those methods are created.

Then, there is a problem is that people might expect all objects written in the same codebase to behave this way, but if there are any performance tradeoffs then this might not be desirable.

Taking all above into account, is this something you would use?

EDIT: Somebody already answered it and this actually look pretty good. I wasn't using bind the right way (using bind inside a constructor). The answer was essentially about doing this:

```
function Person(){
...
this.printName = this.printName.bind(this); 
}

Person.prototype.printName = function(){ console.log(this.name); };
```

But then he deleted it, because I wasn't specific about which bind trick I was talking about, and he probably thought that I mentioned it. Can you please re-add your answer, Mat (if I remember your name correctly), so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: `.bind` or closure are your only options with prototypes. I don't see any issue in using those. I assume (experienced) JavaScript developers know how `this` works and therefore why the method has to be bound this way.

Answer (score 1):

One option to make `bind` more readable is a wrapper like this:

```
    function bound(obj) {
        var res = {};
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj[key].bind)
                res[key] = obj[key].bind(obj);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

and then

```
something.addEventListener('click', bound(this).method);
```

instead of

```
something.addEventListener('click', this.method.bind(this));
```

If you're already on ES6, arrow functions is an option too:

```
something.addEventListener('click', () => this.method());
```